# RemoteCache, RemoteCacheManager, and Lifecycle

Tags: java, datagrid, jboss

I am looking at the documentation for the [RemoteCache](https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/5.1/apidocs/org/infinispan/client/hotrod/RemoteCache.html), [RemoteCacheManager](https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/5.1/apidocs/org/infinispan/client/hotrod/RemoteCacheManager.html), [Lifecycle Start](https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/5.1/apidocs/org/infinispan/lifecycle/Lifecycle.html#start()), and [Lifecycle Stop](https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/5.1/apidocs/org/infinispan/lifecycle/Lifecycle.html#stop()).

I am having a hard time understanding what exactly do the start() and stop() methods do.

The reason that I ask is because I am attempting to remotely stop and start a particular cache. I want to do this so that I can observe the behavior my applications exert during a stopped/started state. i.e I write a test that remotely stops a cache. When this happens, I make a simulated call to see how my software behaves now that the cache is down.

I have tried calling both stop() and start() in the RemoteCache and the RemoteCacheManager on a particular instance, but no exceptions seem to occur by the infinispan dependency. Thus, it is leading me to believe that I am misinterpreting the purpose of these two methods.

My software is calling the remote cache with code that looks as follows:

```
final RemoteCache<String, String> cache = remoteCacheManager.getCache(CACHE_NAME);
if (cache != null) {
    if (cache.containsKey(key)) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
} else {
    throw new Exception("cache null");
}
```

My test is calling the remote cache with some code like this:

```
final Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ConfigurationProperties.SERVER_LIST, serverList);
props.put(ConfigurationProperties.SO_TIMEOUT, 5000);
props.put(ConfigurationProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5000);
rmtCacheMgr = new RemoteCacheManager(props, true);
```

In a test, I might perform something like this to stop the remote cache:

```
rmtCacheMgr.close();
```

Surely, if my software calls getCache, and I set the cache to stopped during my test, it should throw some exception or complain to some level, no?

Answer (score 0):

Configure a New RemoteCacheManager:

```
import org.infinispan.client.hotrod.configuration.Configuration;
import org.infinispan.client.hotrod.configuration.ConfigurationBuilder;

Configuration conf = new 
ConfigurationBuilder().addServer().host("localhost").port(11222).build();
RemoteCacheManager manager = new RemoteCacheManager(conf);
RemoteCache defaultCache = manager.getCache();
```

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Data_Grid/6.4/html-single/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/index.html#part-Set_Up_a_Cache_Manager

Hope this will help. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted and upvote it IF it fits for your question!

Comment: Anup, my question is not necessarily how to set up the remote cache manager, rather what do the start and stop methods do? Surely, the remote cache manager should be able to interact with the boss data grid directly, no?

Comment: -start() and stop() is Lifecycle method. In order to be able to use an RemoteCache, the RemoteCacheManager must be started first: beside other things, this instantiates connections to Hot Rod server(s). Starting the RemoteCacheManager can be done either at creation by passing start==true to constructor or by using a constructor that does that for you (see C-tor documentation); or after construction by calling RemoteCacheManager.start().

Comment: This is an "expensive" object, as it manages a set of persistent TCP connections to the Hot Rod servers. It is recommended to only have one instance of this per JVM, and to cache it between calls to the server (i.e. remoteCache operations).
-RemoteCacheManager.stop() needs to be called explicitly in order to release all the resources (e.g. threads, TCP connections).

Comment: start
-----
public void start()
Specified by:
start in interface Lifecycle

stop
-----
public void stop()
Specified by:
stop in interface Lifecycle

Comment: hmmm i see. i suppose my next question then would be, how would one tell the manager to stop making allowing connections to the hotrod server? so that I can deliberately enforce that during a test, and cause my production software to behave in a non-happy path in regards to the remote cache reading/writing.